# Reference error: variable not defined (in navbar)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, reference, navbar

I can't get my navbar to show an edit profile dropdown after logged in - receiving an error as soon as a log in as an artist (artists=user).

**Error:**

```
ReferenceError: /Users/myfiles/app/views/layouts/boilerplate.ejs:22
    20| 
    21|   <body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
 >> 22|     <%- include('../partials/navbar') %> 
    23| 
    24|     <main class="container mt-5">
    25|         <%- include('../partials/flash') %> 

/Users/myfiles/app/views/partials/navbar.ejs:21
    19|               </a>
    20|               <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
 >> 21|                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/artists/<%=artist._id%>/edit">Edit profile</a></li>
    22|                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    23|               </ul>
    24|             </li>
```

**boilerplate.ejs file w/ navbar partial**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Boilerplate!!</title>

</head>

       <body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
         <%- include('../partials/navbar') %> 
     <main class="container mt-5">
         <%- include('../partials/flash') %> 
         <%- body %>
     </main> 

     <%- include('../partials/footer') %> 


 </body>

 </html>
```

**Partial for navbar.ejs**

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #00305a;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link active" href="/events">Events</a>
            <a class="nav-link active" href="/artists">Artists</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <% if(currentUser) {%> 
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/artists/<%=artist.id%>/edit">Edit profile</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>  
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <% } else { %> 
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/login">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/artists/new">Sign Up</a>
            <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Global variables from app.js**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
})
```

How do I structure my navbar ejs so I can allow logged-in artists to "edit" their user profile? I'm thinking it has something to do with my global variables on app.js so I've included a snippet of the file.

Comment: Kind of a basic question, but... you are importing ejs support, right? It looks like it just doesn't know what to make of the `<%`.

Comment: If I remove it the navbar disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out-- I had to change the name of the ejs variable because I had already defined currentUser:

From:
href="/artists/<%=artist.id%>/edit">Edit profile

To:
href="/artists/<%=currentUser.id%>/edit">Edit profile

The artist's id had already been passed into currentUser so I was able to pull it out of there.